# cmake displays only a few projects in the list

Tags: cmake

I have a lot of libraries in my project and several startup projects. If open the list in IDE, have to scroll through for a very long time to find the one you need.
How can I use presets to limit the displayed list to only those needed?
Maybe there is some example on the Internet where something like this has been implemented?
Thx